# Как взять значение из cmd

Tags: java, swing, cmd, gui

Как взять значение консольной команды sfc /scannow в языке Java и передать его в Progressbar?

```
try {
     Process proc;
     proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sfc /scannow");
     int number;
     number = Integer.parseInt(proc.getInputStream());
     } 
catch (IOException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(sstmadmnUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот примерчик Вам:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String [] args){
        try {
            Process proc;
            proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"sfc.exe", "/scannow"});
            InputStream stdout = proc.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout, "UTF-16LE"));
            String s;
            while (true) {
                s = reader.readLine();
                if (s == null) {
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println(s);
            }
            reader.close();
            stdout.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {

        }
    }

}
```

Тестировал в IDE Intellegi Idea 2018, в терминале был успешный вывод. Вот кусок:

> Проверка ресурсов Microsoft(R) Windows(R), версия 6.0.
>
> (C) Корпорация Майкрософт. Все права защищены.
>
> Проверка целостности всех защищенных системных файлов и замена
>
> неправильных
>
> версий правильными.
>
> SFC [/SCANNOW] [/VERIFYONLY] [/SCANFILE=<файл>] [/VERIFYFILE=<файл>]

Добавьте флаг */scannow*, и Вы получите желаемый вывод.

Обращаю Ваше внимание: команда sfc имеет повышенные привилегии, поэтому для её запуска нужны права администратора. Я запускал IDE с правами администратора. 
К тому же, проверка выполняется довольно-таки долго, Вы должны учесть это в своей программе.

P.S.: существует проблема, которая не даёт запустить команду *sfc /scannow*. Текст ошибки будет примерно такой:

> Защите ресурсов Windows не удается запустить службу восстановления

Дело может быть в том, что Ваша IDE вызывает 32-битную консоль для выполнения запрошенной операции. Решить эту проблему просто. Я проверял на 64-битной версии Windows 10 Pro и IDE Intellegi Idea. Вам следует изменить путь к JDK в свойствах проекта, на 64-разрядный(на моей машине установлен JDK двух разрядностей). Узнать версию, с которого запущен экземпляр Вашего приложения можно так:

```
  System.out.println(System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model"));
```

После этого проверка будет успешно проводиться, а также, весь вывод будет отображаться в назначенном Вами месте(в моём случаем в терминале, смотрите скриншот). Удачи.

P.P.S.: про ProgressBar: парсите полученную строку, которая содержит проценты, получайте число. Дальше дело техники.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как брать из процесса sfc.exe (sfc /scannow)?

Comment: @A.Chernykh один из вариантов: запустите команду в консоли, а затем получите вывод способом, который я описал выше.

Comment: Не получается, наверное это из-за того, что это системная команда и она не передаёт значений.

Comment: @A.Chernykh я обновил свой пост, прочитайте.